# Have I got these simple power calculations right? (for battery consumption)

Tags: power, batteries, current

Lets say an ideal AA battery I have provides 2.0 Watt hours. It could be different, just a quick search for this example.

My very simple load is the battery connected to a 5mm LED. The LED has a forward voltage of 2 or so volts and ideal forward current is 20 mA for good lighting.

Here are my calculations:

```
Load (power) = 20mA * 1.2v(battery) = 0.024W (or 24mW)
Possible life: 2Wh/0.024 = ~83.3 hours = ~3.47 days
```

Is it correct to divide watt hours by watts used, to get hours again? I am a bit tired, although 3.5ish days sounds fairly correct - thought it would be more.

Comment: Sounds about right.

Comment: Note that "2.0 watt-hours" is specified for a certain discharge rate, called a C-rate, and the number will be different for other rates.  "For example: If a battery's capacity was measured over 20 hours to be 2 amps, then the capacity rating would be labelled 80 Amp-hours. However the faster you discharge, the lower the capacity of the battery. If a load of 80 Amps was drawn from this battery, it would probably only last 20-30 minutes."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your AA battery won't provide the 2V for the LED, so you'll need two of them in series. I guess the 1.2V is the cell voltage, so you have 2.4V for two cells. Your LED would then be dissipating 20mA x 2V = 40mW, but the total load on the battery is 20mA x 2.4V = 48mW. The extra 8mW will be dissipated in the LED's series resistor.

So battery life (2 cells) is 4Wh/48mW = 83 hours, like you calculated.

Comment: Thank you, I was too tired to catch the forward voltage being too high for one. This re-enforces some of my calculations.

Answer (score 5):

- See "glossary" at end re mAh, Watts = power , Watt.second = energy..
- Batteries should be rated in Ah capacity for calculation purposes when a linear regulator or constant current load is used.
- Use of Wh capacity may be more appropriate when a switching regulator is used, provided that correct assumptions are made about the battery voltage-time profile.

Even though the answer does not change in this case because this problem is "contrived"* it's dangerous to treat batteries as Watt-hour = energy sources when a linear regulator is used.
  [* Being contrived to provide an example is no problem - it's just that the assumptions made in such cases need to be appreciated so that they don't you atray when some of the parameters are changed.]

For loads which draw a constant current, either because of a regulator or otherwise, it is wiser to treat the battery as a current x time source and work in mAh (or Ah). This is because the battery Watts per mAh changes with time even if the load Watts does not. As the battery voltage falls a load which draws the same mA will consume less energy and dissipate less Watts.

NimH cells are sold with mAh ratings, and usually not with Watt-hour ratings. Interconversion is easy if the correct assumptions are made, but the changes of battery voltage with load make Wh less valuable  with linear regulators.

In the above answer cell voltage has been guessed at 1.2V mean. This may be close to correct but at the same current draw will change with battery capacity, manufacturer,  temperature  and more.

mAh will also change with temperature and load  and some other factors but requires less guess work overall.

When a switching regulator is used the Watt-hour rating becomes more important, as a higher battery voltage (should) result in a lower Iin for a given load. This is especially important when Vbattery varies widely across a discharge cycle. eg Nimh tends to vary from about 1.3V to 1.0V but spends most time in the say 1.25V to 1.1V range at light load and in the 1.2V- to 1.0V- range under heavy load.

Glossary:

Current x time = amp hours = Ah or mAh
 V x I = Watts or mW  = power
 V x I x s = Energy = Watt.seconds or Joules